# sip header Contact private ip. Is it ok?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sip, pjsip

I am working on a sip client and i have some question:

In the sip header the : CONTACT field what ip should contain? The private ip of the client or the gateway ip of the client? Currently using siphon from what I see the contact field is:

```
via: sip/2.0/udp gatewayip;....
Contact: <sip:username@privateIP:port;transport=...>
To: <sip:username22@serverIP;....>
From: <sip:username@serverIP;...>
```

For some reason the INVITE message when trying to make a call doesn t get to the server. Could this be the reason? Can someone please explain? The registration works ok.

EDIT:

I managed to set the Contact field with public ip. The problem though still presists. Could it be because of the tcp socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Axel83 explains, `Contact:` header defines a contacting point for subsequent requests per session basis, this is, it's valid to provide a different `Contact:` in REGISTER and INVITE **but** some systems uses registration as an authentication system, this means, in order to avoid an in-personification attack, any request with a different `Contact:` would be discarded.

Initially, in this last scenario, you would receive a 403 response but, maybe, you can try to test it.

On the other hand, you can be facing a SIP Application Level Gateway (ALG) that can be altering your scenario, this is possible to know by checking REGISTER request received in the server. Maybe, you can provide a REGISTER screenshot.

More in detail, an ALG usually knows about a SIP message reception because of source and destination ports, this is, if it's sent to or from 5060 port (or 5061).

What is the problem with theses entities? that they put themselves in the middle, like a man-in-the-middle attack, and manipulates several communication aspects, like media streams, connections or request forwarding, by means of unknown criteria. This can affect your keep-alive mechanism, new session establishment and several more things.

Main symptom to know that you're behind an ALG is *by sending SIP request with private IP addresses* and, checking in the server side, if received messages contains this private information or if it has been replaced by public addresses. In former scenario, you should be behind an ALG.

In case that you actually are behind an ALG, best way to avoid it would be by not using 5060 port neither as source (client port) or destination (server side) port, this is, for example, if you're currently connecting from client A with IP address A.B.C.D:5060 to server F.G.E.H:5060, try to use: A.B.C.D:5161 <--> F.G.E.H:5161.

Main reason for this to work is because, from server side, checking all traffic going through would be too costly and, ALGs, are applied based on source and destination ports been standard ones.

Please note that, in this proposed work-around, you would need to enable a NAT traversal mechanism on server side (e.g. Asterisk already provides [it](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+nat))

Comment: Hi jcm. thank you for your replay. I wuld like to tell you that register and first camm works ok. I managed to change the Contact fiels to have a public ip.After 2 minutes or 3 from the first call the second call doesn t arrive at the server. Could it be because of the tcp socket? Can the tcp socket get closed from the server after a couple of minutes?

Comment: @justME I know that register works properly but, an ALG, wont give you any problem registering but on following request and, main problem is, that it would be random so it's important to be sure that you're not in this scenario. On the other hand, about the TCP connection, initially, it should be kept alive but this depends on your network provider's and server implementation, because TCP keep-alive mechanism can be disabled. In this scenario, common workaround is keeping it alive from application level, for example, sending SIP OPTIONS messages.

Comment: on the server side how can i check if tcp keep alive mechanism is enabled? I am reregistering the client every 10 min. All the calls from the stack that didn t arrived on the server initially do arrive after a new registration. Based on this I guess it s a tcp issue. Could you tell me how to check on the server d TCP keep alive mechaninsm is disabled or not? Also, for keep alive mechanims on the client I am using pjsua_acc_set_registration. (ios pjsip stack). Do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: @justME If your server is a Linux platform, I suppose so :D, you can check /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time (this indicates time, in seconds, before first keep-alive message), tcp_keepalive_intvl (time gap between keep-alive packets) and tcp_keepalive_probes(number of failed tries before closing the connection). But this can be overtaken by SIP server, for example, Kamailio has his own configuration. About `pjsua_acc_set_registration` it's fine, unless you set _renew_ to false, that would unregister the account.

Comment: The sipserver that is used is Asterisk (Linux platform) and from what i ve seen keepalive is disabled (set to 0) Could this be the issue? Or is there smth else that needs to be set on an asterisk server? Please help. Thank you!!! Regarding pjsua I have this:    for (i=0; i<(int)pjsua_acc_get_count(); ++i) {
        if (!pjsua_acc_is_valid(i))
            continue;
        pjsua_acc_set_registration(i, PJ_TRUE);}

Comment: On asterisk the default value for keepalive is 0  meaning no keep alive right?

Comment: @justME Initially, yes so, if you don't have system keep-alives (you should check tcp_keepalive_* file I previously stated), most probably, your connections between your server and NAT should have been lost. But, please, can you check if, using private IP in Contact:, you receive it with public IP? A capture would help a lot. You can blur sensible information if you want.

Comment: Hi. Contact ip is public! I checked that. On the server side the sip header with all the fields: To, From, Via, Contact all have public ip. Soo...the server does not keep the tcp port opened. If i want to leave it like that is there a way I can open a new socket from the client side before sending an INVITE message to the server? Can I do that with pjsip or the only way to open a new tcp socket would be with a reregistration. Please give me some advices. thx

Comment: @justME Are you using pjsip? good to know that. If all fields are public, I would bet that you're behind an ALG. Are you able to change your server's listening port? If so, try to change it from `5060` to something different (e.g. 5161) and try again (note that you would need to configure Asterisk for [NAT scenarios](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+nat))

Comment: I don't follow you. If the socket on port 5060 is closed can t I open another one with the currently invite message? If I can t do that , than why? Teoreticaly I should be able to open a tcp socket before sending the invite, right? Is there a way to check if the socket is still opened or not? I am working on ios. Could you give me some refferences regarding how to check if the port is a socket is opened or not and how to open it in case is not opened? Can I do that using pjsip? Registration works in the same way right? you are the best!:) thx for your input, by the way!

Comment: @justME Please, check my update for possible problems with ALG. In your case, if you have an ALG, is possible that its trying to reuse the connection with your server, if this is down, it fails and you receive no notification. Once again, this is easier to handle with a couple of captures. Can you, please, provide them?

Comment: I am sending keep alive packets on the same socket, but on the server side there is no keep alive mechanism for tcp. I  checked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43489/discussion-between-jcm-and-just-me)

Comment: could ths ALG be implemented on the client side - or is something that it has to do woth the router from the client side? How can I avoid it from the client application?

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT!! It seems that on the server side there is an ALG. How can I solve this from the client side? Should i open a socket every time I am planing to call ?

Comment: @justME If you can reconfigure your Asterisk, best solution would be update it to listen to a different port (e.g. 5161 instead of 5060) and enable [NAT mechanisms](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+nat). This is because ALG is usually applied if client's source port or server's destination port is 5060, so, by changing it, most probably, you would be able to elude this system.

Answer (score 1):

The Contact header contains the SIP URI where the client wants to be contacted for subsequent requests. That means that the host part of the URI must be globally reachable by anyone.
If your contact contains a private IP (behind a NAT?) then it is wrong, because other peers cannot reach you with that.
However, since the Contact header is used for **subsequent** requests, that is not the cause of your problem.
When you say that the INVITE doesn't get to the server, do you mean that you don't receive any response from it, or you get an error? What is the request URI of the outgoing INVITE? You could make a Wireshark capture to see if it goes to the expected server address.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I did trace with wireshark the packets and i do see the invite sip message going out but on the server side I can t see any traffic from the client

Comment: There is no error, On the client side I do get 408 Request Timeout.

Comment: Ok, so it is a locally generated 408. Did you check in Wireshark if the destination IP/port/transport of the INVITE correspond to the listening address/port/transport of the server? Does your client receive an ICMP notification?

Comment: No it doesn t receive any ICMP messages. Thre registration and the first call wors great. After a while though when i am trying to make a call...nothing happens. The protocol I am using is TCP.